# How does j_security_check work? How do we customize the login API call?

Tags: java, authentication, jsp, single-sign-on, j-security-check

I just started learning about using j_security_check and it seems pretty straightforward but what I can’t seem to understand is how the action knows what api call to handle the login process. Say I have an api set up and I want j_security_check to hit that api and login if successful, how do I go about that?
Also is it editable? Can we change the action name, or how it authenticates? I can’t seem to find any documentation on this. I just see help setting up in the html form and the login-config in the web.xml. Any point in the right direction would be truly appreciated

Comment: It's not clear how would you like to use an authentication. You dhould clirify the problem and post the relevant code. Don't ask many questions at once, narrow the question to a concrete problem and describe what did you try to resolve it. We are not supposed to write a reference to authentification to guide you. You can find it yourself.